# using a 100 volt capacitor to charge a 6 volt battery

Tags: capacitor, charging

Need to charge a 6 volt lead acid battery from a 100 volt 15,000 mfd cap. 
and control the current flow to the battery.

Comment: need to ask an actual question

Comment: You have my permission to do it.

Comment: "Need to [...]" No, you don't. Tell us what it really is that you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your units are, but let's assume that you're talking of a 15,000 uF = 15mF capacitor. Such a capacitor [stores](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng.html) 75J of energy when fully charged at 100V. A 10Ah 6V battery stores about 200kJ - three orders of magnitude more energy.

Assuming that whatever circuit you use to transfer the energy from the capacitor to the battery has 100% efficiency, you'll need about 3,000 energy transfer cycles. That's utterly impractical if you have to switch the connections manually each time.

If the capacitor is part of some charging circuit, then I question why do you even need a flying capacitor to begin with.

**What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think that a capacitor is a solution to that problem?**

If somehow you really do have access to a 15,000 mF = 15F capacitor bank charged to 100V, then certainly this makes some sense. A simple circuit that would do the job would be a buck converter configured as a current source. A flyback converter would work too. You'd need to have switchable taps in either case, so that you could get sensible switching periods. That capacitor bank will be huge - on the order of a cubic metre.

Comment: Charging the cap with a bifilar coil set up like joule theif, Wanted to decant a voltage of six or twelve volts at a few miliamps to recharge lead acid batteries. The output voltage should be six or twelve volts. I experiment with many different things, mechanical and electrical. The easyest thing to do will be to find a buck converter, found a 50 volt imput but nothing any higher.

Comment: @marc The rating on any particular chip only means what you can feed to the chip itself. It's up to you to design the entire circuit to work as you wish, with the voltages that you have. Designing electronics is rarely about copying application circuits.

Comment: @marc Since a joule thief is a boost converter, the obvious question is: what are you stealing those joules from, and why do you up-convert to 100V??

Comment: Kuba, a hand wound bifilar pulsed with a 3904 npn pair in tamdem [piggy backed], 25,000 ohm resistance on the base.
Getting over hundred volts out, rectifying the voltage. The maximum charging of the caps stops at about 110 volts. The battery is a small six volt lead acid. The caps are 100 volts15,000 mf electrolytic from a power amp. Need a circut that will supply about six volts, but only draw a small current, maybe 100ma or so. Don't know if that is possible. I have turned a lot of coils over the years, I experiment for enjoyment , not for employment.

Comment: @marc What is the source of energy into the coil? Why do you even have a coil? All you're telling me is that you have a circuit - what powers it?

Comment: @marc please use real units. "mf" is not a unit (milli-femto-...).